# Pinging two machines (mac and a pc) from a wifi hotspot

Tags: network-share, ping, wifi

I am in India and I use a device like [this(Verizon mifi)](http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/mobilebroadband/?page=products_mifi) to connect to internet(Indian version is called Tata photon WiFi hub), this device can connect upto 5 computers but the problem is that none of these devices can ping each other essentially I can not share files/folders.

I also have a Netgear WNHDE111 wireless bridge and AP but it seems to need an Ethernet connection to work!!

I have turned off firewall on my PC and a MAC. Have tried to configure Netgear WNHDE111 also with no success

I will really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

The cellular/wifi device likely has "AP Isolation" mode turned on. This prevents wireless clients from communicating with each other. If you can get into the configuration of the device, you may be able to turn that feature off.